# Code behaving differently with and without a std::cout statement

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Trying to debug some values in an image (1D array), but found a behavior I cannot understand:

- the code below never hits the `if()` conditions, and nothing is shown to the console.
- by adding back the line `// std::cout << 4 * i << "\t" << 4 * j << "\n";` the code works properly.
- confirmed that the variables `W`, `H` and `step`, when defined inside the function as local variables, the problem doesnt happen.
- also, when replacing the multiplication `step*i` with the division `stx/step`, the problem also doesnt occur.

Running Visual Studio 2019 release x64. The problem seems to do with some compiler optimization, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong!

```cpp
void testcode(int W, int H, int step) {
    int n = 30;
    int h = H/step;
    int w = W/step;
    float* arr = new float[h * w];
    memset(arr, 0, h * w *sizeof(float));
    int stx = 500, ndx = 550;
    int y = 900;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            int cost_idx_sc = i * w + j;
            int cost_idx = step * i * w + j * step;
            // std::cout << 4 * i << "\t" << 4 * j << "\n";
            #if 0
            if ((i >= stx/step) && (i <= ndx/step)) {
                if (j == y/step) {
                    std::cout << (float)(arr[cost_idx_sc]) << "\t";
                    system("pause");
                }
            }
            #else
            if (((step*i) >= stx ) && ((step*i) <= ndx )) {
                if ((step*j) == y ) {
                    std::cout << (float)(arr[cost_idx_sc]) << "\t";
                    system("pause");
                }
            }
            #endif
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    delete[] arr;
}

int main(){
    testcode(2000,1500,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote: why not multiply i to W in cost_idx? step * i * w = i * W.

Comment: If the compiler is optimising away calls to std::cout or system then it's breaking the rules of C++, in other words a compiler bug. That seems unlikely so I would look to your own mistakes first. But it's not impossible of course.

Comment: What have you attempted so far to try to debug the code yourself? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/)

Comment: I took your code and it ran perfectly OK for me (as far as I could tell). Your lack of output in the console may be due to the fact that you never output a `\n`. Try replacing `\t` with `\n`.

Comment: Seems to work just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/zd5zeK

Comment: @Docteur actually cost_idx is never used. it is just debugging code but thanks for the note

Comment: @john tried both \n and \t no output so far.

Comment: @JohnCvelth I it is working properly on the godbolt test bench, but on my machine still nothing happening....

Comment: @RemyLebeau as you can see from my question, changed different cout settings, defined variables inside the function vs functions params, added output to see where the loop is etc..

Comment: @Ahmed have you tried `std::endl` instead of `\n`? `std::cout` output is usually buffered, and `\n` alone is not guaranteed to flush the buffer. `std::endl` outputs `\n` and then flushes.